# sound is turned off. How do I turn sound back on?

Tags: windows-xp

Apparently I have hit the wrong button and turned the sound off on my computer. How do I check and turn the sound back on?

Comment: -1 there is a volume control same as in windows 7.. You should add to the question whether or not you checked that.

Answer (score 1):

Control panel -> sound settings, or in the start menu under accessories->communications

Comment: tell him then what

Answer (score 0):

Look by your clock and see if you have an icon of a speaker with a red X on it.  Right click on the icon to adjust your main sound level.